Apache RP multiple websites root paths
We use apache RP, so users first login, then second login with mfa appeara. On that page user also chooses to which website he would like to go.
We managed to create login page, and mfa also works with drop down item, where user can choose to which website he would like to go.
User can choose between three websites:

website_A.company.com/
website_B.company.com/
website_C.company.com/prod/jobs/

We managed to get RP to work with website_A and website_C. But when we add website_B, which has also root path as website_A. It doesn't work. It depend what we try. Sometimes we are missing static files or site doesn't work.
How to add website_B, so it would work? Or do we need separate reverse proxy?
Thanks.
conf file looks like:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName login.company.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/....crt
...

    Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"

    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require valid-user
        AuthFormProvider file
        ErrorDocument 401 /login.html
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
        AuthType form
        AuthName realm
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation https://login.company.com/company/company.php
        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
    </Proxy>

    #website_C
    ProxyPass /prod/jobs/login.jsp https://website_C.company.com/prod/jobs/login.jsp
    ProxyPassReverse /prod/jobs/login.jsp https://website_C.company.com/prod/jobs/login.jsp

    #website_C static
    ProxyPass /prod/ https://website_C.company.com/prod/
    ProxyPassReverse /prod/ https://website_C.company.com/prod/

    #website_A
    ProxyPass / https://website_A.company.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://website_A.company.com/

    ProxyHTMLExtended On
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /

    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain website_A.company.com login.company.com
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain website_C.company.com login.company.com

    Timeout 5400
    ProxyTimeout 5400

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Location /doSomething>
       SetHandler form-login-handler
       AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation https://login.company.com/.../index.php
       AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation https://login.company.com/do
       AuthFormProvider file
       AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
       AuthType form
       AuthName realm
       Session On
       SessionCookieName session path=/
       SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
    </Location>


</VirtualHost>


By "Apache RP" do you mean the Apache httpd configured as a reverse proxy? "But when we add website_B, which has also root path as website_A. It doesn't work" - but there is NO MENTION of website B in the config you showed here.

Yes. It is reverse proxy. I removed config for website_B, because it didn't work. Or i didn't know how to do it right. I tried it, but it didn't work -  as #website_B
ProxyPass /website_B/ https://website_B.company.com/
ProxyPassReverse /website_B/ https://website_B.company.com/
